# App closed state push notifications icon colour not displaying correctly

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to set an icon and its background colour to my push notification when the app is in closed state but when I am trying to set the colour to #00B3E3 its not setting the same colour but setting something else

This is how I am setting my push notification colour and icon for closed state

[image]

My notification colour is #00B3E3

Is there any restrictions to some colours for the same as when I am setting the colour to RED(#FF0000) it setting the icon background to red.

This is how my notification looks like with #00B3E3, this is not the colour I am expecting.

[image]

#00B3E3 looks like this

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help.

**Edit #1**

My firebase libraries looks like below

[image]

Payload set via postman looks like following

```
{
"registration_ids": [
    "fTJJfGnARvml7FocCkVMmT:APXXXXXXXXXXXXXXEhmCFlclbiSbeOXgwo2w8gNIyEQWoTw0scqt5EThNLpwXXXXXXXXH5TPvUViEjFdXgeXoTH7-qh_3o5s2DlNtZn5frt5RQRSvh_FpDrNRS4HjvU6Ze9J"
],
"notification": {
    "title": "Congratulations",
    "body": "YOU’VE EARNED 15 POINTS"
},
"data": {
    "type": "points",
    "points": 5,
    "title": "Congratulations",
    "short_title": "YOU’VE EARNED 15 POINTS",
    "description": "YOU’VE EARNED 15 POINTS",
    "capping_info": "You've completed 5 Quizzes. This is the maximum number of quizzes you can complete for a month."
}}
```

No colour of icon is sent from payload

Comment: FYI: I have created a new project and the same thing is happening in that project too

Comment: Bro, I create and follow your step and it's working fine in my system can you please put what actually you get when you are in the background?

Comment: @HanifShaikh My result is in my question. When I am trying to set the required colour, it is giving me a darker version of it.

Required and result colour are in my question. Can you check with the same?

Thanks

Comment: My implementation is available on GitHub https://github.com/nawanirakshit/test-notification-colour

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the color is sent from payload as well. If it is sent from payload then the code from manifest.xml won't set. Manifest.xml color is used when payload is not sending any color.

Reference - https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Comment: Colour is only set from Manifest, no colour is set from payload